# Плановное sticky menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, есть вот такой скрипт. На высоте 700px от верха, меню становиться sticky. Но делает это оно слишком резко. Можно добавить немного плавности ?

```
var num = 700;
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.header').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.header').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: Как определить что оно уже достаточно "плавно"?) Что Вы в принципе понимаете под "резко" и "плавно"?

Comment: плавно это хотя бы вот так http://hashiva.s215.upress.link/ ))

Comment: добавьте к классу header transition и будет вам счасьте